# I am developing tetris in SpriteKit and get a strange Error

Tags: swift

I am trying to develop Tetris in SpriteKit. Here is my code:

```
class Array2D<T> {
    let column: Int
    let row: Int
    // #2 
    var array: Array<T?>
    
    init(column: Int, row: Int) {
        self.column = column
        self.row = row
        
        // #3
        array = Array<T?>(count:row * column, repeatedValue: nil)
    }
    
    // #4
    subscript(columns: Int, rows: Int) -> T? {
        get {
            return array[(rows * column) + columns]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            array[(rows * column) + columns] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

My error comes up on this line:

```
 array = Array<T?>(count:row * column, repeatedValue: nil)
```

And this is the error:

> Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'count:repeatedValue:', expected 'unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:')
>
> Replace 'count:row * column, repeatedValue' with 'unsafeUninitializedCapacity:row * column, initializingWith'

Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The array initializer you are looking for is [`init(repeating:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init).

Replace:

```
array = Array<T?>(count:row * column, repeatedValue: nil)
```

with:

```
array = Array<T?>(repeating: nil, count:row * column)
```

Comment: You’re welcome. Please accept the answer by clicking on the gray checkmark to the left to turn it green. That lets others know your answer is solved and it gives both of us some rep points making it more likely that people will answer your future questions.